# How to convert STRING (WYSIWYG) into HTML?

Tags: html, wysiwyg

### ***Hello!***

I have string with WYSWIG syntax like this:

```
# This is h1
#### This is h4

**bold text**
*italic text*
__underlined text__
```

And i want to convert it to normal html tags (`<b>bold</b>` instead of `**bold**`).

---

Do you know how can I do it?

***Thanks in advance!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, solved - there is a library called `react-markdown`, which converts WYSIWYG into react components.